# USB Ports not working in linux

Tags: boot, server, 18.04, usb, logs

we have multiple systems which are installed on the same way.
Now we have a bad situation, ANY USB-Port will not work on two PCs while using ubuntu 18.04.02 server version.

The usb ports working fine on ubunut 18.04.02 (desktop) and windows, so the hardware cant be malfunction.

I tried some stuff:
I already did a bios reset.
Reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04.02 server (which also not work, but if i install it on a other pc (same hardware/modell) it works fine).
I tested different other keyboards/devices.
I tested all usb-ports
In dmesg/sys logs i cant see any new line about usb.
In commands like lsusb there are NO usb devices.

Have you a idea for that ?
I dont understand it, because we have multiple Devices (same model/hardware) which are installed on the same way but on two of 15 devices its not working...

Comment: Instead of adding "solved" to the question, you should post an Answer. On this site, you can answer your own questions.

Comment: The problem was solved by updating the BIOS. This may be interesting to Ubuntu users because the same problem occurred on two similar devices out of 15 devices. VTLO.